# Let $X$ be a set. Build an algebra $\mathscr{A}$, such that $|\mathscr{A}| = 2^p$, for every $p \in \{1, 2, \cdots, s\}$ with $s \le |X|$.

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, solution-verification

PROOF/SOLUTION VERIFICATION:

Let $X$ be a set. Build an algebra $\mathscr{A}$, such that $|\mathscr{A}| = 2^p$, for every $p \in \{1, 2, \cdots, s\}$, where $s \le |X|$.

For $p = 1$, $\mathscr{A} = \{\emptyset, X\}$ works.

Let $1 < p \le s$. Let's take $p-1$ different singletons of elements of $X$, to say something, $\{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \cdots, \{a_{p-1}\}$ and consider the set

$$E = \{\emptyset, X, \{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \cdots, \{a_{p-1}\}\}$$

Then, $\mathscr{A}(E)$ satisfies the required construction.

My justification is the following one:

We have $p-1$ different singletons of elements of $X$.

If $p - 1 = 1$, $\mathscr{A}(E) = \{\emptyset, X, \{a_1\}, X \setminus \{a_1\}\}$.

If $p - 1 > 1$, $(p-2)!$ is defined. So we can get
$$\sum_{i=2}^{p-1} C_n^i = \sum_{i=2}^{p-1}\frac{n!}{i! (n-1-i)!}$$
more elements corresponding to all the possible unions of the singletons.

Now consider
$$(p-1)+\sum_{i=2}^{p-1} C_n^i$$
more elements corresponding to the differences $X \setminus \{x\}$, where $x$ is a singleton or an union obtained before.

Therefore, we are having
$$2 + 2\Big((p-1) + \sum_{i=2}^{p-1}\frac{n!}{i! (n-1-i)!}\Big) = 2^p$$
elements in our algebra $\mathscr{A}(E)$.

A pretty interesting observation, is that $X$ could be infinite and for every $p \ge 1$, it stills working.

Any observation or comment is welcome.

Comment: By "Algebra", do you mean that $\mathscr{A}$ is closed under union, intersection, and complement?

Comment: @VezenBU I mean closed under finite unions, differences, and $X \in \mathscr{A}$.

Comment: It's easier to count the algebra if it's generated by a partition of $X$ with $p$ parts instead.  Then the algebra is naturally put in a one-to-one correspondence with the subsets of the partition, and there are $2^p$ subsets of a set with $p$ elements.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like your problem doesn't need $s$, and could be re-written "Let $X$ be a set,  for every $p$ where $p\leq |X|$, build an Algebra $\mathscr{A}$ such that $|\mathscr{A}| = 2^p$."

Comment: @MW Maybe OP had bounding $s$ w.r.t $|X|$ in mind, just guessing.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: @MW Sounds coherent, indeed.

Comment: My point, more concisely, is to use $$E = \{ \{a_1\}, \{a_2\}, \ldots, \{a_{p-1}\}, X \setminus \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{p-1}\}\}$$ instead (in this comment, I will refer exclusively to this $E$).  This is a partition of $X$, and every element of the algebra generated by $E$ is uniquely written as a union of a subset of $E$.  This provides a bijection between the elements of the algebra and the subsets of $E$.  As $E$ has $p$ elements, it has $2^p$ subsets. (with a little work, it shows the algebra is naturally order-isomorphic to the power set of $E$, but this isn't necessary for your problem)